# Is there a direct elisp way to check if a process is running in an emacs term buffer?

Tags: emacs, process, elisp

I need a check for whether or not a process is still running in my emacs term; started via `(term "/bin/bsh")` and then renamed to, eg. `term-A`.

I have tried `(term-check-proc "term-A")`, but it doesn't show what I what I need, or at least, I don't see how I can use it.

Trying to chase it down by a shell call to `ps afx` (or the like), is problematic if there is more than one `emacs term` active and running the same program, (which in my case, is quite quite possible)...

I really need to know if a process *in a specific emacs term buffer*, `term-A`, is running or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get a buffer's process with `get-buffer-process`:

```
(get-buffer-process "*shell*") -> #<process shell>
(get-buffer-process "*scratch*") -> nil
```

After I exit the shell in `*shell*`, I get `nil` for that buffer too.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems my question is ambiguous.. I need to know if the process I started running within term is still running.. eg. `(get-buffer-process "term-A")` seems to only tell me about the terminal instance itself.. I want to know if the command I entered at the commandline prompt is running or not (that command was started by `(set-buffer "term-A") (term-send-raw-string "cmd-A")`.. .and I do want the terminal buffer's window to remain open.

Comment: Well, you could use `(process-id (get-buffer-process "term-A"))` to get the shell's process ID, and then use `ps alx` and look in the PPID column to see if the shell has any children.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks.. with the PID it's plain saiIng.  (unless elisp can do the child look-up, rather that using `ps` ....